# Does category of finitely generated torsion $G$-modules has enough injectives?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, injective-module, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a profinite group. Then the category of discrete $G$-modules have enough injectives. Now I have a category of finitely generated and torsion $G$-modules with continuous $G$-action. Does injective objects exist in this category. If yes, then how to prove. If no, then any example.

Comment: Crossposted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/364645/does-category-of-finitely-generated-torsion-g-modules-has-enough-injectives#comment920321_364645).

Answer (score 5):

No.  For instance, when $G$ is trivial, you just have the category of finite abelian groups, and I claim that there are no nonzero injective objects in this category.  Every finite abelian group is a direct sum of cyclic groups of prime power order, so it suffices to show a cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/(p^n)$ where $p$ is prime and $n>0$ is not injective.  To prove this, just consider the extension $$0\to\mathbb{Z}/(p^n)\stackrel{p}\to\mathbb{Z}/(p^{n+1})\to\mathbb{Z}/(p)\to 0$$ which does not split.

Comment: Seems the short exact sequence has a little typo or at least little confusion? I suppose you mean $0 \to \mathbb{Z}/p^n \xrightarrow{\cdot p} \mathbb{Z}/p^n \to \mathbb{Z}/p \to 0$, or $0 \to p\mathbb{Z}/p^{n} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^n \to \mathbb{Z}/p \to 0$.

Comment: No, the sequence is correct.  You coud also write it as $0\to p\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\to \mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\to\mathbb{Z}/p\to0$.  Note that $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\cong p\mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}$ by the multiplication by $p$ map.

Comment: I see. It is about the definition of "multiplication by $p$ map". The one in my mind was $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \to \mathbb{Z}/p^n$, $\overline{x} \mapsto \overline{px}$, but you are absolutely right, my definition would then not be an injective map.